# Knockout.js, how to change a value of mapped two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a controller that returns two dimensional array of objects as json. I make a call from my javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/Game/GetBoard", function (json) {
    data = json;
    board = ko.mapping.fromJS({ board: data });
    ko.applyBindings(board, $('.board')[0]);
});
```

I also have the following html:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: board">        
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <td data-bind="attr: { class: Color }"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It generates a nice 2 dimensional html table with nicely colored cells (based on a class that comes from a Color property). How can I now change this color to something else?

I tried: `board[1][1]({Color: 'red'});`, but I get an error saying that board[1] does not exist...

And another question, how can I add more than one class to the binding? I tried:

```
...
<td data-bind="attr: { class: Color + ' some-other-class' }"></td>
...
```

But then I get:

```
class="function b() {     if (0 < arguments.length) {         if (!b.equalityComparer || !b.equalityComparer(d, arguments[0])) {             b.H(), d = arguments[0], b.G();         }         return this;     }     r.T.Ha(b);     return d; } some-other-class"
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping plugin will turn your array into an observableArray and your properties into observables.

For your first case, you would need to unwrap the observable array by doing: `board.board()[1][1]`

For the other question, Color is an observable.  If you are using it in an expression and want to get its value, then you need to do Color().  So, it would look like:

```
<td data-bind="attr: { class: Color() + ' some-other-class' }"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. I am new to knockout and still make those silly mistakes...I still do not understand why `<td data-bind="attr: { class: Color }"></td>` works. Can you explain that?

Comment: The bindings all check to see if they were passed an observable and try to unwrap it.  However, if you use an expression (`Color() + ' some-other-class`) then it is evaluated before it gets into the binding.